# Line toggle in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, macros

I want to write a line toggling macro in Netbeans. 
But I'm just not sure how to do it without affecting 
my clipboard (I don't want it to be changed each time I run the macro) 
I just want it to work like Emeditor, without moving the caret location 
just switching the line with the one above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the right Macro for it:

```
select-line cut-to-clipboard caret-up caret-begin-line paste-from-clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

improved variant of macro:

```
caret-end-line selection-up cut-to-clipboard caret-up paste-from-clipboard caret-down
```